# Issue with getting output from PERL script running on IIS

Tags: java, perl, iis, cgi

Please note the the below subroutine is supposed to print $sting containing a bunch of information generated by another Java program. The issue is that $string ends up being empty, which suggests that the command is not even run. When I run this script outside of IIS, I actually get the output that I expect. Any ideas?

```
sub getStatus{
my $info = shift;
my $env = lc($info->{'enviroment'});
my ($host,$port) = split("\-", $env);
chomp ($host, $port);
my $cmd = "java ./GetStatus $host $port";
my $string = `$cmd`;

print <<ENDOFTEXT;
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Cache Status</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H4>Cache Status</H4>
$string
</BODY>
</HTML>
ENDOFTEXT

}
```

Comment: Try with the full path to `GetStatus`. Also, `environment`.

Comment: I've tried defining the full path to GetStatus and string still ends up being empty. I am almost sure this has to do with IIS setup as running this script from command prompt gives me expected output, but I am not seeing anything in IIS which affect this.

Comment: Cab you `system()` some other command that writes something to STDOUT through IIS successfully? I would suspect it somehow mingles with the started programs STDOUT. You could try the `Expect` module but i doubt that changes a lot. I guess worst case is to have your Java program print its output into some temporary text file that your perl script reads afterwards. Of course that requires some timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I took a look at $ENV{PATH} and noticed that the path to java was not included even after I updated system variables and restarted the IIS site. Unfortunately, you need to restart IIS as a service in order to pick up the new enviroment variables. This is now working.